# How to disable the home button in android 4.0+ versions

Tags: android

I tried following code but it is not getting to disable the home button above 4.0 versions in android

```
public class DHActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dh);
        getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dh, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow()
    { 
           this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);    
           super.onAttachedToWindow(); 
    } 

     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
                Log.i("TESTE", "BOTAO HOME");
                return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);   
        }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

}
```

Comment: you can't catch the home button press in android above versions so , Its not possible to disable...

Comment: But it is working on android 2.2

Comment: yes in lower versions it will work for security reason google not allowing in later versions..

Comment: @mvnpavan maybe you can add this as an answer, becuase it is correct. Google doesn't allow you to override either the home or power button.

Answer (score 2):

In the **lower versions** of android you can catch the home button , in later versions for security reason `Google` not allowing to **override home button** press.

Comment: Even if it's possible to do so in lower versions of android, it's a really bad design, in my opinion. Imagine opening a desktop application that prohibited you from minimizing or closing it.

Comment: yes to prevent those kind of apps google restricted in later versions, but still samsung giving this feature in later versions if we buy samsung mdm..